# sql query: if any of the columns have even one word mentioned in a given array of words, select that entire row

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query:

`select distinct * from tableName where contains ( (column1, column2, column3), 'default' )`

This works fine. Instead of looking at just one keyword 'default' is it possible to mention an array of words and if any of the columns have even one word mentioned in that array of words, select that entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct * 
from tableName 
 where contains ( (column1, column2, column3), 'default' OR 'defalut2')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258227%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: When i am trying to execute the query, i get an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'" . Am i doing something wrong?